# different behavior of script when it runs on crontab

Tags: scripts, cron

I'm trying to write a script that checks if mysql is running, and if not restart it...

i get a script to run perfectly if is called manually from terminal, but when i added to crontab it outputs is totally different...

the code is

```
service mysql status
```

when run from terminal it just outputs

```
mysql start/running, process 2570
```

but when it runs from crontab it outputs

`/usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.
Server version      5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log
Protocol version    10
Connection      Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:         14 min 9 sec
Threads: 1  Questions: 2220  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 684  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 170  Queries per second avg: 2.614`

it seems that the crontab version calls /usr/bin/mysqladmin instead of mysql

how can i change this?

Comment: Not a direct answer, just 2 advices about `crontab`. The environment used for cron is limited and different then `bash` with logged user. Usually the command line during cron script run is not `bash` (in Ubuntu is `dash`, not sure in Debian). So two tips: test in the same command line interpreter used by crontab (or change the sha-bang to use `bash`); and if possbile, provide full paths.

Comment: No, don't do that (change the shell for cron), use the full path to binaries you want to call. So use /use/bin/mysql rather the mysql . See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try enter this paragraph to it:

```
        noadm="false"
        noadm=(v)
```

and to the mysql -v

and it might work fine this way.

Comment: It know outputs "Usage: /etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status" when i call "service mysql -v status"

Comment: with the  noadm=(v) it doesn't log anything after it...